# Goinng live with google app engine application

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I am new to google app engine and deployed my application(php) on GAE but i dont know what i have to do for making it live. Do i have to make changes in my app.yaml file .My app.yaml is looking like this now

```
application: app_id
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
```

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you deployed it, it's live... That's what deployment means...
try to access your app with it's url which looks like:

http://PROJECT-ID.appspot.com